# How to run debug in PyCharm until you reach warning?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am looping through a list of objects in a python program, and I get a `RuntimeWarning` from one or more attempts at calling `numpy.nanmean()`. I would like to inspect the contents of the object that results in the warning being thrown, but I loop through a list > 100 items long, so it's a bit unwieldy to use PyCharm's debug feature to step through each iteration. Is there a way to run the program until a Warning is thrown, at which point I can inspect the offending object?

Comment: Consider using `Exception breakpoints` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-breakpoints.html#exception-breakpoints

Comment: Excellent, that worked, thanks!